# Trying to get the size (in %) of subcategories in a pivot

Tags: google-sheets

I am keeping track of my (stock) portfolio in Google Sheets, as follows:

```
category     subcategory    company  amount
-------------------------------------------
health care  diagnostics     AA       100
health care  diagnostics     AB        50
materials    mining          BA        75
financials   banks           CA        30
financials   insurers        CB        35
financials   banks           CC        10
financials   banks           CD        40
financials   hedge fund      CE         5
health care  equipment       DA        50
```

But now I want to extract some statistics from this, and I'm using a Pivot. Specifically, I want to see:

- the relative size of each `category` in the portfolio
- the relative size of each `subcategory` in the portfolio
- the relative size of each `company` in their `subcategory`

The first two I get done:

[image]

For instance, I can see that:

- category `financials` has a relative size of `30%` in the portfolio
- subcategory `diagnostics` has a relative size of `37.97%` in the portfolio

What is missing however, is the third column, see mockup below:

[image]

I can now see in the last column what the relative size of each `company` is in its `subcategory`:

- Company `CD` is `50%` of the subcategory `banks`
- Company `AB` is `300.33%` of the subcategory `diagnostics`

That last column however, is not calculated but added manually to show what output I am trying to get but am unable to.

Does anyone know how to have this last column as part of the Pivot?

Here is a link to the Google Sheet used: [Pivot](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bkZ8KlggAfI88iYnybE8w-vc_Zuyvu7l4I5DHpnD9xA/edit#gid=1961080926)

Comment: Pr0no, your sheet is shared but private - no access allowed.

Comment: @kirkg13 Apologies! Should be ok now.

Comment: Would an array formula work with you?

Comment: I would be ok with any solution that has the output as I mocked up. It should not even have to be a pivot table; that is just what I thought was the best solution. But I'm ok with any other solution too. I wouldn't know how to implement an array formula in a calculated field or otherwise, though.

Answer (score 6):

Currently, there is no `% by subtotal` option in Google Sheets to show percentages against subtotals for the whole Pivot Table:

[image]

As a workaround, you can display the subtotal percentages by filtering the Pivot Table to display only one subcategory, for example:

Add Filter here and select `subcategory`:

[image]

Then select the desired field, for example, `banks`, and click OK.:

[image]

This should display the subtotal percentages like this:

[image]

Note: You can delete `category` field in Rows to make the Pivot Table cleaner.

You can also submit a feature idea request to Google Workspace, please see instructions on this site: [Submit ideas for Google Workspace and Cloud Identity](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6284762?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

So I found out there are two possible solution using calculated column and another using `arrayformula`.

Option 1: Use a duplicate pivot table. One issue of `getPivotData` function is that it will run in the table calculations stage so it will return empty result. So the solution was to have two clones of the pivot table. One will be used to retrieve the data and the other to retrieve the subtotal.

The formula to use would be

```
=amount/getpivotdata("amount",'Copy of Pivot'!$F$10, "category", category, "subcategory", subcategory)
```

Where `amount`, `category`, `subcategory` without the double quotes are values (references) filled by Google Sheets. While the double quoted ones are column names.

You also need to set `summarize by` to `custom` for it to work.

[image: output]

The only issue I found here is that I couldn't find a way to identify subtotal or total rows, they do have `company` value equal to the first record in the group. If anyone know how to know if I am rendering a subtotal, please let me know.

The second option is to use one pivot table only but reference original data.

```
=amount/SUM(QUERY($A$1:$D,"Select D Where A='"&category&"' AND B='"&subcategory&"'",false))
```

It still shares the same total rows though.

The last option will be the least robust. It would be using `arrayformula` but I don't have that ready at the moment. It is main issue is that changing the column orders or adding new columns will require to keep the position of the refenced columns and move the `arrayformula` columns. Not to mention, handling the empty cells in a category since data is grouped.

Comment: The subcategory Totals now give the same value as the first value in the subcategory (for instance, `banks Total` gives `37.50%` for `Calculated Field 1` but would ideally give `(37.50 + 12.50 + 50.00) 100%`. Is this what you meant by "The only issue I found here is that I couldn't find a way to identify subtotal or total rows, they do have company value equal to the first record in the group"?

Comment: @Pr0no yes. For instance on `banks Total` row, company is equal to `CA` rather than empty.

Comment: Is there a way to then not have any value on the `Total`s rows? So not the `CA` value for instance, but instead just an empty cell?

Comment: @Pr0no not I know of. All my attempts to identify the subtotal row, failed. I tried to use the summarize using sum but that forced all non numeric column access to be returned as 0. Without access to company, category and subcategory. Querying the data is impossible.